# install zeromq for logstash in Solaris 5.10

Tags: installation, solaris-10, logstash

used this: http://zeromq.org/distro:debian to get zeromq in Ubuntu to use it with logstash. Want to achieve same within Solaris. Read that zeromq supports Solaris but only provides a tarball. How to apt-get for Zeromq in Solaris.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is you can't.

Solaris 10 doesn't use repositories for software (unlike Solaris 11 and linux Distro's) so you cant use apt-get or something  like yum or pkg.

Your best bet is to download the source tarball and build it on a Solaris machine, as after looking around there site they only provide the POSIX tarball for unix like systems to build from.